# Procedural attribute macro to inject code at the beginning of a function

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

I'm trying to build a simple attribute which will inject a let binding at the beginning of a function, so the result would be:

```rust
#[foo]
fn bar(){
    // start injected code
    let x = 0;
    // end injected code

    ...
}
```

I've gotten to this:

```rust
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::{quote, ToTokens};
use syn::{parse_macro_input, ItemFn, Item, Stmt};



#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn hello(attr: TokenStream, stream: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input = parse_macro_input!(stream as ItemFn);

    let block = input.block;
    let res = quote! {let x = 1;};

    // doesn't work, can't convert TokenStream into Stmt
    block.stmts.insert(0, res.into());
    TokenStream::from(input.into_token_stream())
}
```

However, I'm having trouble handling these items. For instance, the `block` is of type `Vec<Stmt>`, now a statement is made of pieces (`Local`, `Item` `Expr`, `Semi`) and when trying to work on these pieces, I just get lost. I feel like I'm missing something about how to handle these pieces, but looking at the provided example `trace-vars` is not helping, and a lot of the ressources online are outdated.

I've also tried a very silly approach of creating an `ItemFn` using quote, parsing it, and getting the `Stmt` from it, but then I get another error due to `TokenStream` actually being from two different crates, `proc_macro` and `proc_macro2`:

```rust
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn hello(attr: TokenStream, stream: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input = parse_macro_input!(stream as ItemFn);


    let res = quote! {fn () { let x = 1; } };
    let res = parse_macro_input!(res as ItemFn);

    let block = input.block;
    block.stmts.insert(0, res.block.stmts[0].clone());
    TokenStream::from(input.into_token_stream())
}
```

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> bsub-procedural/src/lib.rs:13:15
   |
13 |     let res = parse_macro_input!(res as ItemFn);
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `proc_macro::TokenStream`, found struct `proc_macro2::TokenStream`
```

Running on

```
[dependencies]
syn = { version = "1.0.67", features=["full", "fold", "printing"] }
quote = "1.0.9"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "silly approach" is actually quite a valid solution in some situation. To parse a `proc_macro2::TokenStream`, use [`syn::parse2`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.67/syn/fn.parse2.html) instead of the macro.

The parsing sure seems wasted, since the result is immediately converted into a tokenstream again. But for small things it's fine. The alternative is to convert all parts of the function to tokens individually, e.g.:

```
let ItemFn { attrs, vis, sig, block } = input;
let stmts = &block.stmts;
quote! {
    #(#attrs)* #vis #sig {
        let x = 1; // <- your extra code
        #(#stmts)*
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the silly approach worked with `syn::parse2`! Regarding the other solution, which is clearly nicer, the error I get is `the trait 'quote::to_tokens::ToTokens' is not implemented for 'std::vec::Vec<syn::attr::Attribute>'`. I have `use quote::ToTokens` imported, and I've checked whether `Attribute` implements it, and it does. Maybe it's the `vec` part which does not? I've added my versions for `syn` and `quote` in case that might be the source, they're both the latest

Comment: @Dominus woops, that's what I get for not testing my code. `#attrs` should be `#(#attrs)*`. I fixed the answer. Should work now.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! By the way, if you have any good proc macro learning ressources, I would gladly read them!

Comment: [This workshop](https://github.com/dtolnay/proc-macro-workshop) is a great proc macro learning resource.